# Как выполнить метод в потоке работы с GUI?

Tags: java, javafx

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Controller instance2 = new Controller();
            instance2.aaa.setText("123");
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    Label aaa;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at sample.Main$1.run(Main.java:22)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Ну и на всякий случай sample.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="aaa" layoutX="164.0" layoutY="93.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

У меня та же самая ошибка. Мне объяснили что она появляется из за того, что работать нужно в одном потоке с GUI. Объясните пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: В классе `Controller` Вы не указали `*.fxml`-файл, поэтому поле `aaa` не может проинициализироваться, отсюда и `NullPointerException`. Посмотрите [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145327/nullpointerexception-javafx-label-settext).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могу понять куда писать loader. В сам класс Controller? Если так, то ругается на : setController - Cannot Resolve Symbol.

Comment: Я давно уже не работал с JavaFX, но ответ на этот вопрос можно найти в любой книге по JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "sample.fxml" ) );
Controller instance2 = new Controller();
loader.setController( instance2 );
Parent root = loader.load();
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
primaryStage.show();

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
//        Controller instance2 = new Controller();
        instance2.aaa.setText("123");
    }
});
```

Comment: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.Label field sample.Controller.aaa to javafx.scene.control.Label
Exception running application sample.Main

Comment: @Newmo Удалите строку `import java.awt.Label`, вставьте `import javafx.scene.control.Label`

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее за то что тыкнули)))! 4х дневным мучениям пришел конец!